# How to implement conditional validation in Zod for a file input field based on a radio button selection?

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I'm currently working on a form validation using Zod with react hook forms, and I'm facing a challenge with implementing conditional validation for a file input field based on the selection of a radio button.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
const formScheme = z.object({
  businessType: z.enum(["PVT Ltd", "Partnership", "Sole Proprietor"], { required_error: 'Business Type is required.' }),
  form120: z
    .any()
    .optional()
    .refine(file => file.length == 1 ? file[0]?.type === 'application/pdf' ? true : false : true, 'Must be a PDF.')
    .refine(file => file.length == 1 ? file[0]?.size <= 3000000 ? true : false : true, 'Max file size is 3MB.'),
})
```

I want to make the `form120` field required only if the `businessType` is "PVT Ltd". In other words, if the user selects "PVT Ltd" as the business type, they must also upload a file using the `form120` field.

I've tried a few things, but I'm not sure how to conditionally require the `form120` field based on the `businessType`. Any suggestions or examples on how to achieve this with Zod would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some exploration, I've come up with a solution to address the conditional validation challenge using Zod with React Hook Forms. If you need to make the `form120` field required only when the `businessType` is "PVT Ltd" you can achieve this with the discriminated union.

```js
export const unionSchema = z.discriminatedUnion("businessType", [
  z.object({
    businessType: z.literal("PVT Ltd"),
    form120: z
      .any()
      .refine((file) => file?.length == 1, 'Form 1/20 is required for PVT Ltd business.')
      .refine((file) => file[0]?.type === 'application/pdf', 'Must be a PDF.')
      .refine((file) => file[0]?.size <= 5000000, `Max file size is 5MB.`),
  }),
  z.object({
    businessType: z.literal("Partnership"),
  }),
  z.object({
    businessType: z.literal("Sole Proprietor"),
  }),
]).and(formSchema)
```

In this schema, I've used `z.discriminatedUnion` to handle different validation rules based on the `businessType`. If the `businessType` is "PVT Ltd" it enforces specific validation rules for the `form120` field, making it required and imposing certain file criteria. For other business types like "Partnership" and "Sole Proprietor," no additional validations are applied.